# Options for access to wired 10/100 ethernet network from a distance beyond 100 meters

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wired-networking

We are trying to wire a building on our campus, into our existing wired 10/100 network. However, the building is beyond 100 meters from the nearest switch and its location logistically prevents the layout of wire either underground or above ground.  Do we have any other options?

Comment: PTP Wireless...?

Comment: Agreed with Techie007... there are instances when structurally you cannot lay or run cable for extended distances.. a PTP wireless system may be your best bet.

Comment: [This company] have a number of wireless Ethernet extenders, though it doesn't look as though you can get Gigabit speeds. I searched the web for `Gigabit Ethernet extender over wireless`, but it's difficult to find non-WiFi products. Your answers below seem to ignore your stipulation that you cannot lay cable, which would otherwise be the obvious solution, though Dennis Schulze has now updated his answer to take account of this. Another possible option is to use point-to-point WiFi with directional aerials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the rule that says 328 feet max (100 Meters) distance on twisted pair before you have to repeat the signal (another switch) which will give you another 328 Feet.  It is all based on the quality of the cable and the amount of attenuation/signal degradation between repeaters/switches/hubs.  I have repeated up to 3 times and works fine.  I think the max is 4 hops.  If distance is too long you start repeating more noise than signal.  Copper to fiber transceiver would be a choice to send signal over 400 meters.

Comment: The question says logistically wire is impossible. They need a wireless link.

Answer (score 0):

You could use glass fiber cable, SFP+ twin-ax for example (and while you're at it, go for 10G, and you should have 4 fibers being laid if you only need 2 - better now than later). Depending on the SFP+ module (of which you need two, to insert into the appropriate SPF+ slots of your switches), distances of several hundred meters will be no problem.

[Example](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/transceiver-modules/data_sheet_c78-455693.html) 
Edit: T think I misread the question, since "wireless" is a requirement. A glass fiber cable doesn't fit this requirement, and you will need some sort of wireless bridge. This [5GHz Gigabit full-duplex antenna/radio combination](https://www.ubnt.com/airfiber/airfiber5/) comes to mind (there are other manufacturers, too). But those appliances usually require unhindered line of sight between them to work properly.